# How to Convert an IEnumerable model object to simple model object in view , MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I have to pass a model object to my create view , so that on submit click this model object gets updated.
But at the same time iam using a list of data in its main Layout for rendering a dynamic menu.

Both use the same model class. But for one i give as

`@model IEnumerable<DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page>`

and in the create view i give as

`@model DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page`

In Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {           
        return View();
    }
```

But this gives me an error in _Layout.cshtml, hence the above actionresult is not even executed.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: source
```

So i think i should pass the Ienumerable object to create view and then convert it there to simple model object, so that it can be updated. Please advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's questionable whether you should have @model directive in your Layout. In my opinion you should render your dynamic menu by using a partial view and an action in your controller invoked from Layout by calling HtmlHelper.Action method, something like this:

Partial view for the menu (file named _Menu.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page>

<ul>
@foreach (var page in Model)
{
    <li>@page.Name</li>    
}
</ul>
```

Action named _Menu in your Home controller (or any other):

```
public ActionResult _Menu()
    {
        IEnumerable<DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page> model = new List<DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page>
        {
            new DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page { Name = "Page1" },
            new DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page { Name = "Page2" },
            new DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page { Name = "Page3" },
            new DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page { Name = "Page4" },
        };

        return PartialView("_Menu", model);
    }
```

This line of code in your Layout to render a menu:

```
@Html.Action("_Menu", "Home")
```

Comment: Thanks.Actually i first tried to render menu using 'RenderSection'. But i had to write down the section on each view. Which i didnt want.Though Partialview came to mind, i ignored it as i thought it is meant for a bigger view. Later i tried passing a model object to my layout. And im quite interested to know if there is a way for conversion in view.

Comment: You're welcome. There are of course many different ways to solve this, but this one, according to my experience seemed most suitable.